# Angularjs factory inject is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a web application in Angularjs. I am making some API calls using $http service. I am using factories to call $http services. I have below controller.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('SavedVechilces',  ['$scope','DeleteVechicle',  function ($scope,DeleteVechicle)
 $scope.deletesavedCar = function (sref) {
            DeleteVechicle.deleteCar(sref.CarID).success(function (resposne) { console.log(resposne) }.error(function (error) { console.log(error)}))
        }
  }]);
})();


RoslpApp.factory("DeleteVechicle", ['$http', '$cookieStore','cfg', function ($http, $cookieStore,cfg) {
    var factoryObject = {};
    var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
    var LoginID = $cookieStore.get("LoginID");
    var cookiePreferredLanguage = $cookieStore.get('PreferredLanguage');
    var urlapi = baseurl + "api/Vehicle/DeleteSavedVehicle";
    factoryObject.deleteCar = function (carID) {
        var request = {
            url: urlapi,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                LoginID: LoginID,
                CarID: carID
            },
            headers: {
                RequestedPlatform: "Web",
                RequestedLanguage: cookiePreferredLanguage
            },
        };
        return $http(request);
    }
    return factoryObject;
}
]);
```

When I run above code I will get Unknown provider: DeleteVechicleProvider <- DeleteVechicle <- SavedVechilce error. I injected DeleteVechicle in my controller. May I know the way I am CarID to the factory and returning response is the correct way? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you added reference of RoslpApp file inside index.html

Comment: Thank you. Yes i am adding reference.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole do you still get error after adding reference variable. the variable should be in global scope

Comment: did you try   RoslpApp.controller

Comment: No. I did not try...

Comment: i added var myapp = angular.module('RoslpApp'); in the top and changed myapp.factory and worked fine. now my problem is     DeleteVechicle.deleteCar(sref.CarID).success(function (resposne) { console.log(resposne) }.error(function (error) { console.log(error)})). I am getting TypeError: (intermediate value).error is not a function error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues, you need to change your controller/factory as,

```
RoslpApp.controller
```

also the request should be,

```
 DeleteVechicle.deleteCar(sref.CarID).then(function(response){ 
  console.log(resposne)
 },function(error){
   console.log(error)
 });
```

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan. I changed above two and working fine. May i know where can i catch success response? Currently $http service working fine but response i am checking inside is null. Am i doing anything wrong in my factory when returning?

Comment: I am writing   return $http(request); so is this is the right way to write in factory? Should i check response here only or in controller?

Comment: It is working. Thank you Sajeetharan. May i know above method i am following to invoke http services is correct one?

Comment: Refactoring? May i get some more input on this?